# setting a var from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties

In Class1 I have a var named "cDte1".  I would like to set it from Class2.

Class1.h:

```
@interface Class1 : UIViewController {

    NSString *cDte1;

}

@property (readwrite,assign) NSString *cDte1;

@end
```

In Class2.m I imported the Class1.h

I then tried this from Class2

```
  Class1.cDte1 = @"test";
```

but that doesn't work.  What did I do wrong?

**EDIT, more info.  If I need to set the var and then show the view the code below doesnt work as I assume there are 2 difference instances of the class?**

```
Class1 *obj = [[Class1 alloc] init];

Class1 *myView = [[Class1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Class1" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

obj.cDte1 = @"7/25/2011";


[self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];


[myView release];


[obj release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set member variables on *instances of classes*, not *classes*.

So you can do something like:

```
Class1 obj = [[Class1 alloc] init];
obj.cDte1 = @"test";
```

edit: in your example, try:

```
Class1 *myView = [[Class1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Class1" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
myView.cDte1 = @"7/25/2011";
[self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];
[myView release];
```

Comment: OK that makes sense... I need to set the vars and then open that class and show it using presentModalViewController.  Are those not 2 different instances of the class?

Comment: please see additional comments above

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it on an instance of the class, not the class itself. Something like:

```
Class1 *instance = [[Class1 alloc] init];
instance.cDte1 = @"test";
```

Comment: please see additional comments above

Answer (score 0):

Create an object from Class1 and then try to access it.

You cannot access properties with class names.

How about

```
Class1 *object1 = [[Class1 alloc] init];
object1.cDte1 = @"Test";
```

Comment: please see additional comments above

Answer (score 0):

```
Class1 *viewController = [[Class1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Class1" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
viewController.cDte1 = @"7/25/2011";

[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];

[viewController release];
```

This should work if the ViewController you'd like to push is an instance of Class1. Make sure to have a corresponding InterfaceBuilder file (Class1.xib).
If you create your views manually (without IB, no .xib) don't call `initWithNibName:bundle:` but just `init`.

Comment: please see additional comments above